# Showing that progression is not arithmetic or geometric

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

The progression $(w_n)$ is defined by:

$$w_ n =2^n - 2n + 2 $$

I must show that this progression is not arithmetic and also that it is not geometric. I know how to show that a progression is arithmetic or geometric but I never worked with this type of exercise.

What shall I do?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason by contradiction.  If a sequence were arithmetic, then consecutive terms would have a common difference $d$.  If a sequence were geometric, then consecutive terms would have a common ratio $r$.  Show that no such $d$ nor $r$ exist.

---

I should also add that it is unnecessary to do the computation for general $n$:  it suffices to find *particular* terms of the sequence that fail to have such $d$ or $r$.  For example, if you simply compute $w_1, w_2, w_3$, you can tell right away that the sequence is neither arithmetic nor geometric.

Answer (score 1):

$$w_ n =2^n-2n+2$$
$$w_ {n+1} =2^{n+1}-2(n+1)+2$$
$$w_ {n+2} =2^{n+2}-2(n+2)+2$$

1. If $$w_n-w_{n-1}=w_{n-1}-w_{n-2}$$ you have arithmetic series
2. If $$\frac{w_n}{w_{n-1}}=\frac{w_{n-1}}{w_{n-2}}$$ you have geometric series